# Code to simulate deadlock

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am testing my application I need some code that **stable** simulates the deadlock on database site (sql script if possible).

Thank you.

**ADDED:**

[Reproducing deadlocks involving only one table](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/01/reproducing-deadlocks-involving-only-one-table.aspx)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Can you reword it a little bit? Obviously the two people below understood you well enough, but I'm not quite following you. Do you mean code that "stably" simulates a deadlock? What will you be doing after there is a deadlock? Do you just want to prove that it can happen?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The best way would be to use tables you already have. 
Create two tables -- table-a, table-b
For a test you can even update the same column with the same information
so you don't affect any real data.

For instance
UPDATE table_a set ID = ID where ID = 100;

Open two sessions to the same database.
On one, run

```
BEGIN TRAN
update table_a set ID=ID where ID = 100;
```

On two run

```
BEGIN TRAN
update table_b set ID=ID where ID =100;
```

Then, copy the update statements to the opposing sessions and run at the same time.
In one,

```
update table_b set ID=ID where ID =100;
```

In two

```
update table_a set ID=ID where ID = 100;
```

I just tried this now and got on MS-SQL

```
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 56, Line 1
Transaction (Process ID 23) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `sp_getapplock` system stored procedure to take what ever locks to need on your sample code.

Strictly speaking, this is a [Dijkstra semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). Still damn useful though

Comment: `sp_getapplock` won't throw an error. It will either wait for the timeout to expire, or (if there is no timeout), return `-3` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method similar to the one posted above -->

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl1 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, col INT)
CREATE TABLE Tbl2 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, col INT REFERENCES dbo.Tbl1(id))
```

Script to be used in Query Window #1

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT dbo.Tbl1 (id, col) VALUES (2, 999)
```

Script to be used in Query Window #2

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT dbo.Tbl2 (id, col) VALUES (111, 2)
```

Script to be added to Query Window #1

```
INSERT dbo.Tbl2 (id, col) VALUES (111, 555)
```

For additional details on this, refer to http://ajitananthram.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/scripts-to-force-a-deadlock-in-sql-server/