# Simulate deadlock with more than 2 processes

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

How to Simulate deadlock with more than 2 processes in SQL Server test environment? Can someone help me with the code? Just to clarify my question again, I don't want deadlock simulation with only 2 processes. I know how to produce deadlock with 2 processes but am unable to produce it with more than two processes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code to simulate deadlock](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/309/code-to-simulate-deadlock)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you know how to simulate it with 2, you know how to simulate it with 3, or with N. You have to build a *cyclic* graph:

- 2 nodes: A->B->A  (process A waits on B, process B waits on A)
- 3 nodes: A->B->C->A  (process A waits on B, B waits on C, C waits on A)
- ...
- N nodes: P<sub>1</sub>->P<sub>2</sub>->...P<sub>n</sub>->P<sub>1</sub>

To construct the P<sub>x</sub>->P<sub>y</sub> primitive (Process X waits on Process Y) use your favorite blocking mechanism. For example, row locking on a specific key P<sub>1</sub>->P<sub>2</sub>->P<sub>3</sub>->P<sub>1</sub>:

```
CREATE TABLE rows (key INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

1) P<sub>1</sub>, from session 1:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO rows (key) VALUES (1);
```

2) P<sub>2</sub>, from session 2:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO rows (key) VALUES (2);
```

3) Have P<sub>1</sub> wait on P<sub>2</sub>. From session 1:

```
SELECT key FROM rows WHERE key = 2;
```

4) Continue with P<sub>3</sub>, session 3:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO rows (key) VALUES (3);
```

5) Add the P<sub>2</sub>->P<sub>3</sub> wait, in session 2:

```
SELECT key FROM rows WHERE key = 3;
```

6) To complete the cycle, add the P<sub>3</sub>->P<sub>1</sub> wait, in session 3:

```
SELECT key FROM rows WHERE key = 1;
```

As the wait graph created a cycle, the 3 processes are now deadlocked. In a short while the engine deadlock detection mechanism (which periodically walks the wait graphs looking for cycles) detects this cycle and breaks it by choosing a victim and aborting it's transaction then raising error 1205 in the victim session.

To extend to N nodes, repeat steps 4) and 5) as necessary.